# MySql subquery runs instead of returning error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, in-subquery

I faced some weird mysql subquery issues ...

```
UPDATE site_plugin_products_items 
    SET item_distributor = 176
WHERE item_id in ( 
    SELECT item_id 
    FROM `site_plugin_products_field_values` 
    WHERE value_val in ( 554, 1384  , 785 )
)
```

I the problem is:

Result that query updated ENTIRE table site_plugin_products_items with item_distributor = 176

If i ran the subquery individual:

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM `site_plugin_products_field_values` 
WHERE value_val in ( 554, 1384  , 785 )
```

I get the following error because i put the wrong field, it was supposed to be value_product, not item_id

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'item_id' in 'field list'

Why did this happen ? Shouldn't the big query return an error instead of messing the entire table ?

Lost 2 years when I saw the result, and didn't know if I have a close backup :)

Comment: do you have item_id in site_plugin_products_field_values?

Comment: nope, that's the weird thing.

Comment: if you don't have item_id column in site_plugin_products_field_values table how you can to select it???

Comment: It's using the item_id from the site_plugin_products_items table, which of course will always be the same as item_id in the site_plugin_products_items table - so every record matches.

Comment: Exactly, that table doesn't have the item_id field and it updated ALL the items from the first table.

Comment: You are executing the code inside php  .. and don't manage error message?

Comment: Simple solution - change item_id in your subquery to be the field you should be using.

Comment: I ran it inside phpmyadmin and it returned success ~20.000 records updated.

Comment: show us structure of your tables

Comment: The table structure is irrelevant. Only important thing is the second table doesn't have that field item_id and the sql didn't crash.

Comment: It also runs in my phpmyadmin, but gives an empty resultset. It seems the subquery returns false, and checks the rest of the query accordingly. But since there are not false values, there is no return.

Comment: indeed what @NigelRen says that's why you should always quantify the columns with the table name like so. `UPDATE site_plugin_products_items 
    SET site_plugin_products_items.item_distributor = 176
WHERE site_plugin_products_items .item_id in ( 
    SELECT site_plugin_products_field_values.item_id 
    FROM `site_plugin_products_field_values` 
    WHERE site_plugin_products_field_values.value_val in ( 554, 1384  , 785 )
)`  or use ofcource shorter aliases. This will prevent it from happing in the future.

Comment: Lessons learned. Never ever again run an update command in production if you don't know exactly what you are doing

Comment: Change to a multi-table `UPDATE` from a subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the query -

```
UPDATE site_plugin_products_items 
    SET item_distributor = 176
WHERE item_id in ( 
    SELECT item_id 
    FROM `site_plugin_products_field_values` 
    WHERE value_val in ( 554, 1384  , 785 )
)
```

As `item_id` doesn't exist in the `site_plugin_products_field_values` table, it will use the column from the `site_plugin_products_items` table.

As this will always be the same as the condition (`item_id` will always equal itself) it will update every row.

I tried something to prove this (to myself) using...

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE id in ( select customerID from user u)
```

This runs, but the user table doesn't have a customerID.  BUT if I add the alias to the customerID field...

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE id in ( select u.customerID from user u)
```

This fails.

Simple solution - use aliases to ensure which table your using per column and use the right columns in the first place.  Although I won't mention backups!

Comment: Exactly, but is this something normal ? Is it mentioned in sql documentation ? I expected it break and return some error :)

Comment: Now that's a funky situation. Personally, since every column starts with the name of the table it's in, it's practically impossible to get into a situation like this. But I wonder, is it mentioned in the documentation somewhere? It seems the inner query is also searching from the table of the outer query.

Comment: "It seems the inner query is also searching from the table of the outer query" @kry not seems the inner qeury has column acces to the outer query that's why co-related subqeuries are possible.